# How to cancel http requests?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm tring to cancel HTTP request using `aSubject.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_SUCCEEDED);` but it dont work. The code is given below. Can anyone please correct it?

```
function(aSubject, aTopic, aData)
{
    if ("http-on-modify-request" == aTopic)
    {
        //get the http request url
            var url = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel).originalURI.spec;

        //get the referer of http request (this error gives an error; dont know why :( 
        var a = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel).getRequestHeader("referer");

        //Cancel http request from other domains 
        if (url.split('//')[1].split('/')[0] != a.split('//')[1].split('/')[0])
        {
            //the code below don't work! Someone please correct it.
            //code to cancel http request
            aSubject.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_SUCCEEDED);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question you asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167145/how-to-block-http-request-on-a-particular-tab

Comment: ya, its almost the same. But the prob is that  the previous as well as the code above dont block the http request. So, I'd like the above code to be corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because NS_BINDING_SUCCEEDED isn't an error code (yes, the documentation seems to be wrong). What you actually want to use is `Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED`.

By the way, you seem to be comparing the host name in the URL. Given that you already have an nsIURI object this can be done easier:

```
var requestHost = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel).originalURI.host;
var referrerHost = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel).referrer.host;
if (requestHost != referrerHost)
{
    aSubject.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
}
```